# Java Timer Class actionPerformed is update by two seconds

Tags: java, swing, timer, actionlistener

I am currently implementing a program that is a simple basketball scoreboard.  For the scoreboard, I am using the javax.swing.Timer class built into java.  I am trying to get the display to decrement one second every time actionPerformed is called by the timer.  As of now, it is being decremented by two each time actionPerformed is called.  Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Also,  I'm sorry if I'm not asking this correctly or being too vague.  I'm new here.  If you need clarification or need me to fix something, please let me know.  I've included snippets and then the full code at the very end.

This is the part of my code where the timer is instantiated:

```
Timer clock;
/.....
clock = new Timer(1000, this);
clock.addActionListener(this);
```

And here is where it is updated (in actionListener method):

```
if(event.getSource() == clock){
        if(seconds > 0 && seconds < 60){
            seconds--;
        }else{
            if(seconds == 0 && minutes != 0){
                seconds = 59;
                minutes--;
            }else{
                if(minutes == 0){
                    clock.stop();
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                }
            }
        }
        if(seconds < 10){
            clockLabel.setText(minutes + ":0" + seconds);
        }else{
        clockLabel.setText(minutes + ":" + seconds);
        }
    }
```

Here is all the code for my program:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class BasketballScoreboard extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
JPanel panel;
JButton exit;//Button to exit program
JButton resetScores;//Button to reset both scores
Timer clock;
JLabel score;
JLabel fouls;
JLabel addOne;
JLabel addTwo;
JLabel addThree;
JLabel addFouls;
JLabel bonus;
JLabel homeBonus;
JLabel awayBonus;
JLabel clockLabel;
JLabel clockControls;
JButton resetFouls;
JButton addHomeFoul;
JButton addAwayFoul;
JButton home2;//Button to add 2 points to home score
JButton home1;//Button to add 1 points to home score
JButton home3;//Button to add 3 points to home score
JButton away1;//Button to add 1 points to away score
JButton away2;//Button to add 2 points to away score
JButton away3;//Button to add 3 points to away score
JButton startClock;
JButton stopClock;
JLabel home;//Home team name
JLabel away;//Away team name
JLabel homeFouls;
JLabel awayFouls;
private int homeFoulsNum = 0;
private int awayFoulsNum = 0;
JLabel homeScore;//Home score
JLabel awayScore;//Away Score
private int homeScoreNum = 0;
private int awayScoreNum = 0;
private int seconds = 00;
private int minutes = 8;
public BasketballScoreboard(){
    GridLayout scoreboardLayout = new GridLayout(14,3);

    panel = new JPanel();

    exit = new JButton("Exit");
    exit.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    exit.addActionListener(this);

    clockLabel = new JLabel(minutes + ":0" + seconds);
    clockLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    clock = new Timer(1000, this);
    clock.addActionListener(this);

    startClock = new JButton("Start Clock");
    startClock.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    startClock.addActionListener(this);

    clockControls = new JLabel("Clock Controls: ");
    clockControls.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    stopClock = new JButton("Stop Clock");
    stopClock.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    stopClock.addActionListener(this);

    score = new JLabel("Score: ");
    score.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    fouls = new JLabel("Fouls: ");
    fouls.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    bonus = new JLabel("Bonus: ");
    bonus.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    homeBonus = new JLabel("");
    homeBonus.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    awayBonus = new JLabel("");
    awayBonus.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    addFouls = new JLabel("Add Foul: ");
    addFouls.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    addOne = new JLabel("+1: ");
    addOne.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    addTwo = new JLabel("+2: ");
    addTwo.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    addThree = new JLabel("+3: ");
    addThree.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);


    resetScores = new JButton("Reset Scores");
    resetScores.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    resetScores.addActionListener(this);

    resetFouls = new JButton("Reset Fouls");
    resetFouls.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    resetFouls.addActionListener(this);

    home = new JLabel(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Home Team Name"));
    home.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    away = new JLabel(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Away Team Name"));
    away.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    home1 = new JButton("Home +1");
    home1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    home1.addActionListener(this);


    home2 = new JButton("Home +2");
    home2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    home2.addActionListener(this);
    home2.setMnemonic('h');

    home3 = new JButton("Home +3");
    home3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    home3.addActionListener(this);

    addHomeFoul = new JButton("Home Foul +1");
    addHomeFoul.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    addHomeFoul.addActionListener(this);

    addAwayFoul = new JButton("Away Foul +1");
    addAwayFoul.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    addAwayFoul.addActionListener(this);

    away1 = new JButton("Away + 1");
    away1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    away1.addActionListener(this);

    away2 = new JButton("Away +2");
    away2.addActionListener(this);
    away2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    away2.setMnemonic('a');

    away3 = new JButton("Away +3");
    away3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    away3.addActionListener(this);

    homeScore = new JLabel("" + homeScoreNum);
    homeScore.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    awayScore = new JLabel("" + awayScoreNum);
    awayScore.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    homeFouls = new JLabel("" + homeFoulsNum);
    homeFouls.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    awayFouls = new JLabel("" + awayFoulsNum);
    awayFouls.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    panel.setLayout(scoreboardLayout);

    panel.add(new JLabel(""));
    panel.add(clockLabel);
    panel.add(new JLabel(""));

    panel.add(new JLabel(""));
    panel.add(home);
    panel.add(away);


    panel.add(score);
    panel.add(homeScore);
    panel.add(awayScore);

    panel.add(fouls);
    panel.add(homeFouls);
    panel.add(awayFouls);

    panel.add(bonus);
    panel.add(homeBonus);
    panel.add(awayBonus);

    panel.add(addOne);
    panel.add(home1);
    panel.add(away1);

    panel.add(addTwo);
    panel.add(home2);
    panel.add(away2);

    panel.add(addThree);
    panel.add(home3);
    panel.add(away3);

    panel.add(new JLabel(""));
    panel.add(new JLabel(""));
    panel.add(new JLabel(""));

    panel.add(addFouls);
    panel.add(addHomeFoul);
    panel.add(addAwayFoul);

    panel.add(clockControls);
    panel.add(startClock);
    panel.add(stopClock);


    panel.add(new JLabel(""));
    panel.add(new JLabel(""));
    panel.add(new JLabel(""));

    panel.add(resetScores);
    panel.add(resetFouls);
    panel.add(exit);

    this.add(panel);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    if(event.getSource() == home1){
        homeScoreNum++;
        homeScore.setText("" + homeScoreNum);
    }
    if(event.getSource() == home2){
        homeScoreNum += 2;
        homeScore.setText("" + homeScoreNum);
    }
    if(event.getSource() == home3){
        homeScoreNum += 3;
        homeScore.setText("" + homeScoreNum);
    }
    if(event.getSource() == addHomeFoul){
        homeFoulsNum ++;
        homeFouls.setText("" + homeFoulsNum);

        if(homeFoulsNum >= 6 && homeFoulsNum < 9){
            homeBonus.setText("\u2713");
        }
        if(homeFoulsNum >= 9){
            homeBonus.setText("\u2713\u2713");
        }

    }

    if(event.getSource() == away1){
        awayScoreNum++;
        awayScore.setText("" + awayScoreNum);
    }
    if(event.getSource() == away2){
        awayScoreNum += 2;
        awayScore.setText("" + awayScoreNum);
    }
    if(event.getSource() == away3){
        awayScoreNum += 3;
        awayScore.setText("" + awayScoreNum);
    }
    if(event.getSource() == addAwayFoul){
        awayFoulsNum++;
        awayFouls.setText("" + awayFoulsNum);

        if(awayFoulsNum >= 6 && awayFoulsNum < 9){
            awayBonus.setText("\u2713");
        }
        if(awayFoulsNum >= 9){
            awayBonus.setText("\u2713\u2713");
        }
        }

    if(event.getSource() == exit){
        System.exit(0);     }

    if(event.getSource() == resetScores){
        homeScoreNum = 0;
        awayScoreNum = 0;
        homeScore.setText("" + homeScoreNum);
        awayScore.setText("" + awayScoreNum);
    }

    if(event.getSource() == resetFouls){
        homeFoulsNum = 0;
        awayFoulsNum = 0;
        homeFouls.setText("" + homeFoulsNum);
        awayFouls.setText("" + awayFoulsNum);
        homeBonus.setText("");
        awayBonus.setText("");

    }

    //Here is where the event handling for the timer comes in.
            //I believe this is where the problem is.

             if(event.getSource() == clock){
        if(seconds > 0 && seconds < 60){
            seconds--;
        }else{
            if(seconds == 0 && minutes != 0){
                seconds = 59;
                minutes--;
            }else{
                if(minutes == 0){
                    clock.stop();
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                }
            }
        }
        if(seconds < 10){
            clockLabel.setText(minutes + ":0" + seconds);
        }else{
        clockLabel.setText(minutes + ":" + seconds);
        }
    }

    if(event.getSource() == startClock){
        clock.start();
    }

    if(event.getSource() == stopClock){
        clock.stop();
    }


}

public static void main(String[] args){
    BasketballScoreboard first = new BasketballScoreboard();
    first.setTitle("Scoreboard");
    first.setSize(350, 300);
    first.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    first.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Comment: usually better to not decrement your seconds, but to read the real value, so any delay will not be detected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem in next lines :

```
clock = new Timer(1000, this);
clock.addActionListener(this);
```

You add your `ActionListener` 2 times, because of that your code execute 2 times. So, remove `clock.addActionListener(this);` , and all will work.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I missed that!